# Excel VBA (rows reference)

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to refer to certain rows to do something in VBA.

The code is something like below:

```
Sub test()

Dim k As Long
k = 9
Rows("5:k").Select

End Sub
```

I am trying to make my rows dynamic by changing the k value each time. however I am not sure why it cannot select the rows and the code don't work. Any ways to go around this issue? If I substitute k with 9 directly, the code works. But this does not happen.

Am I supposed to select something like `rows("5:k(value)).select` ?

Comment: change to `Rows("5:" & k).Select`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VBA can't recognise the k variable inside the " "

Try something like:

```
Sub test()
Dim k As Long
k = 9
Rows("5:" & k).Select
End Sub
```

k is outside the " " so VBA recognises it as a variable and the & tells VBA to concatenate the value of k onto what's inside the " "